# Parse Error, unexpected function line 1

Tags: php, wordpress

I keep getting the following error, and i actually have no clue why - i spent way way to long trying to figure it out - but no luck so far.

Error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'function' (T_FUNCTION) in /home/g  
/crm.dk/wp-content/plugins/oa/lib/php/bill.php on line 1
```

Code:

```
<?php
/******************************************/
/*               Generalt                 */
/******************************************/
function update_stuff($sStuff)
{
....
....
....
....
]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: did you mean `}` instead of `]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function closing bracket is wrong

```
<?php
/******************************************/
/*               Generalt                 */
/******************************************/
function update_stuff($sStuff)
{
....
....
....
....
}
```